# Uniquely identify a unix process

Tags: bash, unix

I'm currently writing a bash script to kill a process and then start it again.

I'm using

```
    ps -ef | grep Cp1252
```

to return the list of processes based on the file encoding.

Finding the process based on file encoding is not ideal, as other processes may also have this string.

I need to uniquely identify two processes, but they have quite generic process names:

```
/user/jdk/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java
```

My question is, is there any way to add a flag or a unique identifier to a process?
Or indeed, is there any other way I can solve this issue?

Thanks,
Dearg

***UPDATE***

I found a solution to my problem, I found that I can use the PPID to uniquely identify each process. The command name of the process associated with the PPID is distinctive enough so that I can tell what is a normal Java process, and what it is that I want to restart.

Thanks for all your help anyway, it certainly helped me to narrow down the alternatives! :-)

Comment: With `ps -ef` you have many columns, one of them being `STIME` which tells you when the process was launched. That can be very handy.

Comment: Ideally, you record the specific process ID when the process is started.

Comment: If you start some java app and the process name is as you showed above - maybe there is a way to retrieve the command line parameters which were used to start the process. There, you could find out which java app is started and you would be able to determine, which of those java apps is the one you wish to restart. Just an idea - did not investigate if there is a standard unix way to retrieve that information.

Comment: `pgrep -fl Cp1252` will show matching processes with all the arguments.

Comment: [http://superuser.com/questions/27748/how-to-get-command-line-of-unix-process](How to get command line of unix process) is about retrieving a processes command line arguments. Maybe it provides you with ideas.

Comment: The normal procedure is that the process writes its own PID to `/var/run/<ProcessName>` as soon as it starts up.

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. Although STIME is handy, I'm not sure I can rely on it enough to uniquely identify this process?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a helper script to start the process and record the pid in a file. Just make sure to delete the file when the process stops (which could be done by the wrapper again).

something like

```
#!/bin/bash
PIDFILE=/path/to/pid-file
COMMAND=YOUR_PROGRAMM_HERE

# optionally check if pid-file exists
if [ -e ${PIDFILE} ]; then
   echo "${PIDFILE} already exists, assuming ${COMMAND} already running"
   exit 1;
fi

${COMMAND} &
WAITPID="$!"
echo ${WAITPID} > "${PIDFILE}"

# cleanup on signal
trap "kill ${WAITPID}; rm ${PIDFILE}; exit" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP

# optionally wait for the program to be done
wait ${WAITPID}
rm "${PIDFILE}"
```

so to restart your process, just read the pid from `/path/to/pid-file` and send the appropriate signal.

If you can modify the source code of the processes you run, I recommend adding an option to record the pid from within the process itself.

Comment: Having an extra file for that deems me as a bit less robust compared to some "stateless" solution. What I mean with that, is that if the script doing the file management gets interrupted, the file is still there and the process not running, then the script restarted... it could end in funny situations. If this solution is sufficient depends on the robustness needs, maybe. Also, possibly the java app is not always started by the same script, which could as well interfere with this solution.

Comment: that's why I recommended the solution of adding the PID-File creation to the process itself, but if this is not possible, this will act as a proper workaround for this issue. it is safer than any pgrep, ps -ef | grep hack. And I personally would probably write it in a sane fashion, which would not only check if the pid file is still there, but also if the process is still running and has the same commandline, etc, etc. plus I'd write the whole thing in a way, that it would handle most killing signals and do a proper cleanup.

Comment: Not sure if that would improve things. If the app needs restarting, possibly it does not terminate properly by itself (faulting) -so the deletion of the file might not be guaranteed. Also I see a race condition then between the script to terminate the app and the app, registering. Without thinking too deeply about it, at least that is what my gut tells me. On other systems there is "safety infrastructure" handling such situations.

Comment: This is pretty much the way that many daemons do it. If it really bothers you mkdir is atomic so creating a lock directory is safer than creating a lock file. Some OS/Distro also have flock(1) which may be useful you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments eveybody. @dwalter I am particularly interested in your suggestion to record the pid from with the process itself. I think I can use java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName(); to this end, and get the PID from there. Would this be how you would do it?

For background info, the java processes I'm interested in are started remotely by a user. I need to be able to restart the processes myself then on the server, hence the script. 
The PID would need to be stored in a file, as you say above, on the server itself then right?

Comment: Dearg: Sorry, I have no idea how this would be done in java, but there are others that might be able to help you. And yes you would need to store the PID in a file on the server. Just make sure when adding the PID-File creation to delete the file whenever the process is terminated (this also implies terminated on error).